# How to compute the integral of a simple function in a domain delimited by 4 linear functions?

Tags: integration, area, fluid-dynamics

I have 4 linear functions defined on $[x_1, x_2]$:

$$f:x \mapsto \alpha_f \cdot x + \beta_f ~~~~~~~~ f':x \mapsto \alpha_f \cdot x + \beta_f + \gamma_f$$

$$g:x \mapsto \alpha_g \cdot x + \beta_g ~~~~~~~~ g':x \mapsto \alpha_g \cdot x + \beta_g + \gamma_g$$

$$\alpha_f, \alpha_g, \beta_f, \beta_g \in \mathbb{R}, ~~~~\gamma_f, \gamma_g \in \mathbb{R}^{+*}$$

Let us call $\mathcal{A}_f$ (drawn in green in the picture below) and $\mathcal{A}_g$ (drawn in red) the following areas:

$$\mathcal{A}_f = \{(x,y)\in [x_1,x_2]\times\mathbb{R}, ~~f(x)\leq y \leq f'(x)\}$$

$$\mathcal{A}_g = \{(x,y)\in [x_1,x_2]\times\mathbb{R}, ~~g(x)\leq y \leq g'(x)\}$$

Let $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{A}_f \cap \mathcal{A}_g$ be the intersection of the two previous areas.

[image: areas schema]

I want to compute the integral over $\mathcal{A}$ of the function $H:\mathcal{A}\subset\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined as follow:

$(x,y) \mapsto k\cdot (f'(x)-y), ~~~~k>0$

The goal is to design an algorithm to compute the value. I know hot to find the value with a lot of `if`s (is $g$ above $f$? etc.) but I feel like there may be a simpler analytic solution I cannot get my hands on.

---

A possible physical interpretation of the problem is the following:

Assume in the 3D world, the $x$ axis is horizontal, $y$ axis is vertical (as represented on the picture), and $z$ is a third (horizontal) axis so that $(x,y,z)$ is an orthonormal set.

The surface $z=cst$ of the picture represents a contact surface between two (full) fluid containers, in contact only through $\mathcal{A}$. With $k=\rho\cdot g$, what we are looking for is the pressure force applied by the fluid in one container (the green one) on the fluid of the second (the red one).

---

For the sake of completeness, let us note that the actual inputs of the problem are the 8 intersection points between $x=x_1$ or $x=x_2$ on the one hand, and $f$, $f'$, $g$, $g'$ on the other hand (from which it is trivial to compute the $\alpha$s, $\beta$s and $\gamma$s).